# Is there a clone of Snoke in the Sith Temple?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker, snoke

When Rey entered the Sith Temple, you could see a head in a tank that looks very similar to Snoke's head.

Is it a clone?
Why was it kept? Or is it a clone that has not yet been revived?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You get a better view when Ren enters the temple at the start of the film. The Emperor has a big jar full to the brim with Snoke clones.

[image]

The film's novelisation indicates that there are three of them and that they're all alive.

> A flash of lightning illuminated a huge glass tank, containing three creatures, liquid life being pumped into them through mechanical umbilicals. They were all the same creature, he realized with a start, with wrinkled skin and an oversized bald head and features caught in a state of everlasting anguish. They were all Snoke.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Expanded Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

---

It's not clear why Palpatine needs all those clones but I think we can reasonably assume that if Kylo Ren hadn't become Supreme leader (killed fighting Snoke's guards, for example), then Palpatine would have considered decanting another Snoke and putting him back into control of the First Order.

Comment: For that matter, it could just as easily be the case that snoke needed regular replacement (bodily deterioration) or that these were practice attempts before the "final version" we saw in the other movies was unleashed.

Comment: @user64742 - Sure, but if these were failed Snokes, the Emperor wouldn't keep them floating in vinegar.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that makes sense. Regularly scheduled replacements waiting on standby is still a potential guess though. Furthermore, he might keep some so that if the timing is right he can have two snokes be in two different places (one on hologram talking to Ren, for example, if the other was unable to get a signal). After all, nobody would dare question supreme leader snoke being a puppet.

Comment: @Valorum Those Snokes have paid the price for their lack of vision...

Comment: Didn't he say that he made snoke? He could have meant that more literally than simply turning him to the dark side.

Comment: Poor Andy Serkis. He deserved better. Right, Smeegol?